# Find all <a> tags in which first attributes isn't 'title'

Tags: c#, regex, visual-studio-2015

I'm trying to fix my site to meet WCAG 2.0. This means that all links in my site must have a title. To do it right and not miss any `<a>` tags, I'm ading title to each link as a first attribute :

```
<a title="..."
```

But this site has a lot of links and I'm struggling to find all the links without a title. Can anyone help me with a regular expression that I could use to find all tags that start with `<a` but the next letter isn't 't'?

If someone has an answer on how to find specific tag without specific attribute it will be even better! *I'm working on visual studio 2015*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, it is not a good idea to use regular expressions on a complex system like a DOM. However, in your (simple) example, you might get along with:

```
<a(?:(?!\btitle\b)[^>])*>
```

This ignores links with a title attribute, regardless where they are. See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/xK7zU8/2).

---

<sup>Remember that it will fail on e.g. `<a href="http://python.org" data="Here comes a title">This one fails</a>` not matching it in the way you intented.</sup>

Comment: I guess you reduce the chance of failure by checking for `title="`,

Comment: @JamesWood: True but even this is not 100%.

Answer (score 1):

How about this one?

```
(<a )(?!title)
```

Matches:

```
<a >
```

But not:

```
<a title="..."
```

Try it [here](http://regexr.com/3e6v6).

Comment: Thanks! Working great!